# Enable-Migrations error when trying to run the command

Tags: nuget, entity-framework-6

I am trying to run the command Enable-Migrations in the NuGet console but I keep getting the following error

```
    PM> enable-migrations
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Server stack trace: 
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further research, I found tucked away a little bit of information on the internet, this is a deceptive error, you get this when trying to perform the enable-migrations on a **website**, this needs to be performed on a **web application**

Comment: And a quick work-around is to put all entities to a class library.